# How to search array of structures in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have an array of structures, each structure with fields 'input' and 'output'. Input values are binary arrays, output values are integers.
Let's say I have a specific binary array, for example A = [0 1 1 0 1 0]. How do I find the element in my array that has value in input field equal to A?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html)

```
logicalIndexOfElement = arrayfun(@(x)all(x.input==A),yourStructure)
```

Call [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) on `logicalIndexOfElement` to get the linear indices of the elements in `yourStructure`.